# Static html link to WP7 app by app-id

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I'd like to create a link to another app from my app. I once read on msdn that you can just open a url with a specific pattern (e.g. `windowsphone.com/apps/<app-id>`), but I cannot find this documentation anymore. Is this still possible, or are there other ways to link to other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this format should work:
www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=fd40c569-2681-48df-9ff3-53ffd80aa9b5

Comment: Ok, seems to work. Do you know the msdn doc where it's described?

Answer (score 1):

It is called as Deep Link. I hope you're referring to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_URIassociations) link

Comment: Well, not really. But it looks pretty helpful nevertheless, thx.